# Finding children of element without an id or class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following code structure:

```
<ul class='menu'>
    <li>
         Main Menu
         <ul class='hide'>
             <li>SubMenu1</li>
             <li>SubMenu2</li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
         Main2
         <ul class='hide'>
             <li>Sub1</li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way for me to have a jQuery click event on `Main Menu` and `Main2` in a generic way that will remove the class 'hide' of the correct children each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way, which uses *event delegation* and only runs when the `li` element and not its children was clicked:

```
$('ul.menu').on('click', 'ul.menu > li', function(e) {
    if(e.target === this) {
        $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('hide');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/5HtY6/)

Comment: +1 for `e.target === this` to prevent clicks in the nested `ul` from triggering the handler.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("ul.menu > li").on("click", function () {
    $(this).children("ul").removeClass("hide");
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/dpkBL/

Comment: Best possible answer, I think.

Comment: Btw. It is worth mentioning, that it works in jQuery since version 1.7.

Comment: @Tadeck: Yes, since the version wasn't specified in the OP I assumed the latest one. Good point though.

Comment: I don't think it's the best answer, at least it is not recommended from my point of view. See my post for why.

Comment: @refp: If changing the markup was an option then I would totally agree. However, I get the impression that is not an option from reading the question.

Comment: @refp: Delegating events is a heavy solution in comparison to just binding them. I also think, as Andrew Whitaker said, that there is nothing about dynamic content in the question that is being answered here. I still think _this_ is the best answer as it is simple and does not unnecessarily delegate events.

Comment: @Tadeck check out my post again, I read the jquery documentation and came up with an alternative solution that will fit the required specification. Now I see that Felix King wrote the same thing but in a shorter post.

Comment: @refp: I looked at your answer and you are partially right (btw. I corrected your JavaScript snippet, it didn't work, now it does). Simple `event.target === this` check could make it work only for the text OP mentioned, but is it really necessary? If he wraps it in anything, it will stop working. And from my experience, if it is possible, it will happen. Andrew Whitaker's solution is simple and will withstand such changes, but your solution is also worth +1 (which I give you).

Comment: @Tadeck Thanks for correcting my code, I typed it out directly in the browser without testing it - appreciated! The problem that I've come to realize with SO (I haven't been here for long) is that people tend to up-vote the shortest/fastest answer available, without thinking of the consequences of the described solution. I always try to elaborate my answer enough to make the OP think things through before implementation.

Answer (score 2):

#### Dont always do what the crowd tells you, at least think about it for a while!

I bet people will recommend you to use a selector such as `ul.menu > li`, but please remember that this will not only trigger a click event when you click on the text "Main Menu", but also when you click on any of the other content inside the matching `li`.

If you'd like to implement a show/hide toggle you are far better off wrapping the text "Main Menu" inside it's on element, and then use something as the below to alter what you may want to alter.

```
$(<main menu text selector>).siblings (<siblings selector>);
```

---

#### Still want/have to follow the crowd?

If this is the case I'd recommend you to at least do it with a little twist to prevent what I previously described.

(*edit*: revised version after reading the jquery documentation for elements)

```
$('ul.menu > li').click (function(e){
  if (e.target === this) {
    $(this).children ('.hide').removeClass ('hide');
  }
});
```

```
$("ul.menu > li").click (function () {
  $(this).find ('.hide').removeClass ('hide'); 
});

$("ul.menu > li > *").click (function () {
   return false; // prevent event from bubbling up 
});
```

---

#### Sample implementation of recommended version

The below will bind a click-event-listener to `.menu-toggle`, when the event is fired the siblings (ie. the tags who are in the same scope as the clicked `.menu-toggle`) matching `.hide` will have their `class="hide"` removed.

*Javascript*

```
$(".menu-toggle").click (function () {
  $(this).siblings ('.hide').removeClass ('hide'); 
});
```

*HTML*

```
<ul class='menu'>
    <li>
        <span class="menu-toggle">Main Menu</span>
         <ul class='hide'>
             <li>SubMenu1</li>
             <li>SubMenu2</li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
         <span class="menu-toggle">Main2</span>
         <ul class='hide'>
             <li>Sub1</li>
         </ul>
    </li> </ul>
```

---

Comment: Though, to be fair, the question does specifically mention the constraint of "an element without an id or class" so maybe wrapping the text in its own element is out of the question?

Comment: Well, from the OPs code, there is no other content that could be clicked.

Comment: See my edit, there are things to be done without causing potential buggy experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [child selectors](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/). I think that is what you want.

```
$('.menu > li').click(function () { 
    $(this).children('ul').removeClass('hidden'); 
});
```